# How can I load multiple sites in different context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, session, silent

I want to create a page that "silently" queries other pages. It then crawls them for a result. When it's done querying all the pages, then it should calculate its own result according to the results retrieved.

What I meant with silent is,

1. the other web site's code shall not appear on my page, nor affect it in any way
2. I want each other page to be queried in a different session (like when I open a new tab for each in my browser) or something similar. So that there will be no namespace problems.

I heard chrome would offer something that might be helpful for that?

**edit** This is NOT about crawling web pages. It is for fetching data from other local stand-alone projects

**edit2** I am just looking for an alternative to simply looping URLs and querieng them, because there are namespace issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access pages from other domains with JavaScript unless the domain explicitly allows your domain.

Typically you would use a server-side language for this, or better, use the website's public API. If they don't have a public API they probably wont appreciate you crawling their site.

Comment: <<If they don't have a public API they probably wont appreciate you crawling their site.>> All is said!

Comment: I know... same-origin-policy. But since I am using it for our local network there is no such problem. and there is no API. There are some costum test pages and I need to get data from them.